# How do I cast a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, casting

I have an example like the one below in C++ where I receive a pointer to base class, `exampleParent`, and would like to cast it to a pointer to the inherited class `example` (in reality I just want to call a function on `example`) . The caveat is that the inherited class is templated. In the example below, I know the template is of type `int` so there is no problem. In general, what would be a good way to do this if I am not aware before hand the type of the template?

```
class exampleParent{};

template<typename P>
class example: public exampleParent
{
public:
    int do_something() const
    { 
        std::cout<<"I am doing something"<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

boost::shared_ptr<const exampleParent> getPtr()
{
   return boost::make_shared<const example<int>>();
}

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<const exampleParent> example = getPtr();
    auto example_ptr = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<const example<int>>(example);
    return example_ptr-> do_something();
}
```

One solution I propose is to change the code to something like this:

```
class exampleParent{};
class something_interface: public exampleParent
{
public:
    virtual int do_something() const = 0 ;
};

template<typename P>
class example: public something_interface
{
public:
    int do_something() const override
    { 
        std::cout<<"I am doing something"<<std::end;
        return 0;
    }
};

boost::shared_ptr<const exampleParent> getPtr()
{
   return boost::make_shared<const example<int>>();
}

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<const exampleParent> example = getPtr();
    auto example_ptr = boost::dynamic_cast<const something_interface>(example);
    return example_ptr->do_something();
}
```

This would work, but it feels a bit of a hack: `something_interface` should not really exist, as it has no object oriented interpretation in itself.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is actually a pretty standard concept in C++: the interface which does nothing other than create entry points for others to add their implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If you can make `exampleParent` an abstract class (if you can modify that class at all), that would be the best:

```
class exampleParent
{
public:
    virtual ~exampleParent() = default;
    virtual int do_something() const = 0; 
};
template<typename P>
class example: public exampleParent
{
public:
    int do_something() const override
    { 
        std::cout<<"I am doing something"<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Then you don't need a cast to invoke that method.

If you cannot touch this `exampleParent` class, go on with the intermediate one as you proposed, but remember to actually inherit `exampleParent` and don't throw exception, just make the method pure virtual:

```
class intermediate: public exampleParent
{
public:
    ~intermediate() override = default;
    virtual int do_something() const = 0;
};
```

Otherwise the only way is to do `dynamic_pointer_cast` for all possible types and check the cast result, because different instances of template class are just different types in general. Of course it doesn't make sense if there is infinite number of possible template parameters `P`.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot modify exampleParent, so I'll follow the second advice